# PYTHON: Continually iterating over row(s) and changing values based on values within the row until condition is met

Tags: python, pandas, iteration, overriding

I have a data frame that contains rows of staffing values (upper limit), and allocations.

I need to iterate over each row repeatedly until my allocation reaches my staffing value. My allocation begins at 0. Once my allocation meets my staffing value, move on to the next row.

This is just the first part of the program I am building, later I will have more constraints, and is why I don't just set my Allocation to the value of my Staffing Value.

I've tried the following, but I recieve and error that FutureWarning: get_value is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use `.at[]` or `.iat[]` accessors instead.

```
for row in springdf.index:
    q = springdf.get_value(row,'Allocation')
    if q:
        p = springdf.get_value(row, 'StaffingStandardValue')
        while q < p:
            springdf.set_value(row, 'Allocation', q+1)
```

Also attempted:

```
for row in springdf.index:
        q = springdf.iloc(row,'Allocation')
        if q:
            p = springdf.iloc(row, 'StaffingStandardValue')
            if q < p:
                 springdf.set_value(row, 'Allocation', q+1)
```

But received the error: `__call__() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`

I need to actually over-ride the values of the old Allocation and change the dataframe when "Allocating", not just return a result. This dataframe will eventually be output into an excel file.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If by "continually iterating" you mean "cyclically iterating", you may want to look into `itertools.cycle()` (and also make sure you have an exiting condition).

Comment: I thought when using itertools.cycle(), you can not actually override/alter values within the dataframe, just return a copy. Is this correct?

Comment: The no-go operation is row deletion. Modification is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For indexing values, I would recommend using `df.loc[]`, and you can select the column by name: `df['column_name']`. Putting these together you get:

```
for row in springdf.index:
    q = springdf['Allocation'].loc[row]
    if q:
        p = springdf['StaffingStandardValue'].loc[row]
        while q < p:
            springdf['Allocation'].loc[row] = q + 1
            q = springdf['Allocation'].loc[row]
```

The alternative, as your error messages prescribe, is:

```
for row in springdf.index:
    q = springdf.at[row, 'Allocation']
    if q:
        p = springdf.at[row, 'StaffingStandardValue']
        while q < p:
            springdf.at[row, 'Allocation'] = q + 1
            q = springdf.at[row, 'Allocation']
```

I have not tested it myself, but I have a feeling that the second option is faster performance-wise.

Edit: I just tested it and the second option (using `df.at[]`) is over 1000x faster (10.1ms vs 14.2s) for a 10row by 2column DataFrame of random numbers.